# Symfony Insert into sub table

Tags: symfony-1.4

As i am new to symfony framework, for my client symfony website doing the maintenance. i have tried to insert a record into a new table, which was actually a sub table of a already existing table.

But i am not able to write the insert query in this. which shows the error only.

Please check and provide the solutions for the below code,

```
public function executeUpdatednc(sfWebRequest $request)
    {
        $patient_id = $_REQUEST['pid'];

        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->update('patient')
        ->set('isadmindnc', '?', 1)
        ->where('id = ?', $patient_id)
        ->execute();

        $datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");


#####       Here i need to write the sub query to insert into the new table, Please suggest #####


        //$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
        //$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('INSERT INTO patient_phone SET ph_pid = ?', $patient_id);
        //$query->setParameter(1, $items);
        //$result = $query->getResult();        


    }
```

Comment: you're using 1.* version I think, but tagged as `symfony2`..

Comment: Yes which is symfony 1, is there any option to do this, any idea?

Comment: sorry, I'd help you with pleasure, but I've never tried v1.*..

Comment: Are you using doctrine ORM and schema.yml?

Answer (score 0):

For me, simple way to resolve this problem (for update):

```
 $patient = Doctrine_Core::getTable('patient')->findOneById($patient_id);
 $patient->setIsadmindnc(1);
 $patient->save();
```

For insert:

```
 $patient = new Patient();
 $patient->setIsadmindnc(1);
 $patient->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
<?php
class InsertCarController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/insert', name: 'app_insert_car')]
    public function index(Environment $twig, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $auto = new Autovoorraad();

        $form = $this->createForm(AutoType::class, $auto);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
            $model = $form->get('model')->getData();
            $type = $form->get('type')->getData();
            $prijs = $form->get('prijs')->getData();
            $voorraad = $form->get('voorraad')->getData();
            $gewicht = $form->get('gewicht')->getData();

            if ($prijs > 10000){
                if ($voorraad >= 1){
                    if ($prijs % 2 == 0){
                        if ($gewicht % 2 == 0){
                            $auto->setPrijs($prijs);
                            $auto->setVoorraad($voorraad);

                            $entityManager->persist($auto);
                            $entityManager->flush();

                            $this->addFlash('success', $model . ' ' . $type .' is toegevoegd!');
                            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_car');
                        } else {
                            $this->addFlash('success', 'Gewicht is geen even getal!');
                            return $this->redirectToRoute('app_insert_car');
                        }
                    } else {
                        $this->addFlash('success', 'Prijs is geen even getal!');
                        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_insert_car');
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->addFlash('success', 'Voorraad is niet groter dan 1!');
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('app_insert_car');
                }
            } else {
                $this->addFlash('success', 'Prijs is niet hoger dan €10.000!');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('app_insert_car');
            }

        }

        return new Response($twig->render('insert_car/index.html.twig', ['carform' => $form->createView()]));
    }
}
```